# filter related entries by category

Tags: categories, relationships, related-entries

EE2.7.2

I have a native relationship field 'related_products' pulling in multiple entries from a products channel. 
Most products are in 2 top level categories - group_id 1 and group_id 2.
I want to pass the category_url_title in my link.

The code below returns both the categories in the url:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="featured_products" dynamic="no" limit="1" url_title="featured" status="open" disable="pagination|member_data|category_fields"}
{related_products limit="12"}
    <a href="{site_url}brands/{related_products:categories}{category_url_title}{/related_products:categories}/{related_products:url_title}" title="View product details">LINK</a>
{/related_products}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If I add 'related_products:categories limit="1"' to the code as below, it will return just one category - always from only group_id 1.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="featured_products" dynamic="no" limit="1" url_title="featured" status="open" disable="pagination|member_data|category_fields"}
{related_products limit="12"}
    <a href="{site_url}brands/{related_products:categories limit="1"}{category_url_title}{/related_products:categories}/{related_products:url_title}" title="View product details">LINK</a>
{/related_products}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I can't seem to find a way to filter the 'related_products:categories' to show the second group of categories.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get what you finally want, but to show the second group of categories try using the [show_group](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#show-group) parameter to the categories tag (with the category group id):

```
{related_products:categories show_group="2"}{category_url_title}{/related_products:categories}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. After reading the docs, I'd tried all the other tags listed without success. This really needs to be added to the Relationship Docs page.